# Batch script for scanning each line of keywords in the command output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to capture the iPerf result in a batch script. The last few lines of output are like

```
[ 23]   0.00-15.22  sec   107 KBytes  57.8 Kbits/sec   32             sender
[ 23]   0.00-15.00  sec  63.7 KBytes  34.8 Kbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-15.22  sec   100 MBytes  55.4 Mbits/sec  711             sender
[SUM]   0.00-15.00  sec  92.9 MBytes  52.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

I need to find the line that includes keywords `[SUM]` and `receiver`.
My current solution is, I know it must appear in the second-to-last line, so I directly search for that line.
The code is at below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

iperf3 -c iperf.scottlinux.com -i 1 -t 15 -P 10 -p 5201 -R>>rawdata.txt 2>&1
call :FilterResultLine rawdata.txt 2 resultLineContent
for /F "tokens=6,7" %%a in ("%resultLineContent%") do (
  echo Bitrate [DL]: %%a %%b>>result.txt
)
pause
exit

:FilterResultLine %rawdata% %resultLineNumber% %resultLineContent%
set /A firstTail=1, lastTail=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
   set /A lastTail+=1, lines=lastTail-firstTail+1
   set "lastLine[!lastTail!]=%%a"
   if !lines! gtr %~2 (
      set "lastLine[!firstTail!]="
      set /A firstTail+=1
   )
)
set "%~3=!lastLine[%firstTail%]!"
goto :eof
```

However, if the output format changes, this may be unstable.
I want to know whether the batch script can search for keywords in each line?

Comment: Have you seen [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) ?

Comment: You Can Do double findstr to filter and catch your line

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks! I did it. But it seems like much slower than my original solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this example :

```bat
@echo off
Title Filter and find a line with findstr
REM In this example the file rawdata.txt is in the same folder with this batch file
Set "InputFile=%~dp0rawdata.txt"
If Exist "%InputFile%" ( 
    Goto Main 
) Else ( 
    echo( & Color 0C
    echo( Check the location of this file "%InputFile%" & Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak>nul & Exit 
)
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Main
    echo( ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo( Showing All lines without filtring
    echo( ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (echo %%a)
    pause
    echo( ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo Find only lines with only "[SUM]" in their contents
    echo( ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%InputFile%" ^| findstr /I "\[SUM\]"') do (echo %%a)
    pause
    echo( ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo Find only lines with "[SUM]" and "receiver" in their contents
    echo( ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in (
    'Type "%InputFile%" ^| findstr /I "\[SUM\]" ^| findstr /I "receiver"'
    ) do (echo %%a)
    echo( ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pause
Exit /B
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```